# Узнать причину 500 ошибки

Tags: php, apache, nginx, debian

У меня есть сервер. На нем размещен сайт. На сайте пытаюсь загрузить большой файл эксель. Файл грузится но когда начинает записывать в базу - выбивает 500 ошибка.

Как можно отследить из-за чего она возникает? Может параметр надо какой сменить или что

```
OS: Debian 9
CP: VestaCP
apache+nginx
mysql
```

Comment: Лог ошибок есть на сервере и обычно описание возникающих ошибок записывается в него.

Comment: уровни логирования в apache и расположение конф.файлов:

https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8+error_log+%D0%B8+access_log+%D0%B2+apache

Answer (score 1):

Вот так впишите в настройки nginx (настройки вашего сайта):

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log  warn;
```

А вот так в настройки Apache вашего сайта:

```
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Так вы выведете ошибки в отдельный файл и сможете посмотреть ошибку и ее исправить.

Так же могу посоветовать для nginx увеличить размер запроса, а точнее размер body:

```
client_max_body_size 8M;
```

Это необходимо вписать в файл /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.
Для php можно сделать аналогичную вещь

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M // для файла
post_max_size = 40M  // для запроса
```

Это необходимо вписать в файл /etc/php/<ваша версия php>/apache2/php.ini

Ну это естественно первоначальные вещи. Надо в первую очередь курить логи.